# How often can I get the star loot bonus?

Tags: clash-of-clans

Sometimes after I get my star loot bonus, I get the chance to do another one immediately afterwards, and other times I have to wait awhile to be able to do it again, why is this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will reset 24 hours after you achieve 5 stars in multiplayer battles, however, if the current star bonus isn't achieved in 24 hours, another one will be available immediately after it is completed.

For more info see [here](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Bonus).